# Are there baked goods with highly spongey texture, to the point where they can recover their shape after folding in half?

Tags: baking, bread, cookies, sponge-cake, flatbread

Does a type of baked good exist so full or air bubbles and spongey that if you folded a slice of the baked good in half, it returns to its original shape? If so what was it?

Comment: Many breads will do this - but not typically the mass-produced supermarket varieties.

Comment: Hi Samuel, the basic question is an interesting one. The wording you chose was a bit unfortunate, as it made it eligible for closure (e.g. we explicitly forbid asking for recipes), so I changed the formulation of your question body somewhat, allowing it to stay open.

Comment: Some flatbreads will do this (so long as you don't crease them too hard) - but they're not spongy.  Do you require both sponginess and foldability?

Comment: I'd try doing a sponge cake with a lot of egg whites, but I haven't actually tested this.

Answer (score 1):

Injera (the Ethiopian bread usually made from teff) is quite spongy and will definitely recover its shape from folding, at least if the folding is gentle.